# How to render object inline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, render, inline

I have an object that renders vertically. Is there any way where I can render each item horizontally. I've tried:

```
<%= render :inline => @feed_items %>
```

And I get this message in my log: 
(undefined method `encoding' for #
Did you mean?  encode_with):

Edit: I got it to work with the following code but was curious if there was a way to do it with render :inline.

```
<% @feed_items.each do |feed| %>
  <%= image_tag feed.picture.url(:medium) %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: What is `@feed_items`? Could you provide an example of its contents?

Comment: @feed_items are microposts that contains an image and some content.

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you are looking for?

Comment: @Gerry I edited my question. I'm trying to get the images to display horizontally instead of vertically. I can get it using .each but was curious if I can get it to work using render :inline

Comment: You could do it adding the proper _html_ code to `inline`, just as your current solution does. But it will be a mess, i would advise it every time, it is much better (and cleaner) to render a view/partial with the format you need, even if that partial is only 3 lines.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

```
render inline: "<% products.each do |p| %><p><%= p.name %></p><% end %>"
```

Though it violates MVC, putting view in controller